# Teamcity e-mail certain address when build fails

Tags: email, teamcity

I use TeamCity Enterprise 2017.

I want to send an email to a given e-mail address (which is not mine), let's say 12345@example.com every time when one of my builds fail. Is that even an option? If not, are there any other options as to do something else when a build fails?

Cheers,
P.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest option will be to create new "fake" user with that email address, then go to his **My Settings & Tools** > **Notification Rules**, and create new Email Notifier rule for Build fails.

Remember to give this user proper permission to your project.

Comment: I'm going to try that out if I do not find any other way (and probably I won't...)